# how to determine how many jQuery objects are on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I determine the number of jQuery objects on a page?

I want to use the number of elements as a sort of weak benchmark for page complexity.  I'm thinking that if I can reduce the number of elements that jQuery knows about , the page might run more efficiently.

Does this make sense?

Is it as simple as doing a * select and counting the results?

---

related:
[How can I clear content without getting the dreaded “stop running this script?” dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923987/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/size/

```
var elementCount = $('*').size();
```

Although this might be more what you want:

```
var elementCount = $('body').find('*').size()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var n= 0;
for (var i in jQuery.cache)
    n++;
```

Now `n` holds the number of elements jQuery has ‘touched’ (added data to, such as event handlers).

Previously this used to be a whole lot, as it would ‘touch’ every element it was even *checking* for data. This unpleasantness is fixed in jQuery 1.4.

As for clearing content, yes, you can use `innerHTML= ''` to remove all the content without giving jQuery the chance to detach its data so very slowly. If you know there are no ‘touched’ elements inside the element that's a win, but otherwise it's a potential memory leak until the page is reloaded, as unused `jQuery.cache` data stays around.

Using `live()`/`delegate()` event binding avoids adding data to its target elements, which can allow you to use this short-cut more freely. However if you have a lot of events to bind and they're not selectors that are very easy to match quickly, this can make event handling slow.

(Because there is no browser-native speedup like `querySelectorAll` for matching elements against a particular selector as delegation needs to do; this is proposed for Selectors-API level 2.)

Comment: +1 - I was wondering about that. I knew jQuery added a serial number to elements, but didn't know where jQuery referenced them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elementCount = $('*').length;
```

This doesn't really have much to do with jQuery except insofar as it's a handy way to get the answer.